# How compute the RMSE between two 3D array giving as output another 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, math.sqrt

I have two 3-dimension arrays `actual.shape` = `[333,71,57]` and `predicted_cnn.shape` = `[333,71,57]` [time, latitude, longitude]. Keeping the time fixed I can plot those two arrays as a 2-D map.

When I compute the RMSE root mean squared error between two arrays I use: `sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual,predicted_cnn))` and I obtain a scalar.

Would be possible to compute the same quantity without having a scalar but an RMSE value for each point [latitute, loongitude](time fixed)? I would like to obtain the spatial distribution of the RMSE.

I would need `spatial_rmse=sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual,predicted_cnn))` with `spatial_rmse.shape`=`[0,:,:]`

thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to illustrate what you tried. Specifically, what do you mean by a "3D array"? Are you using numpy?

Comment: And what does "latitude" and "longitude" have to do with anything in your question? What do you mean by "RMSE value for each point [latitute, loongitude](time fixed)"?

Comment: If you want to compute the error for each pair of points individually, I don't see how **Mean** Squared Error fits into this. The RMS of a single value is just the value itself.

Comment: ok sorry for the bad question. actual and predicted_cnn (question edit) are two 3 dimensional arrays (yes numpy) representing the evolution in time of temperature. I would like to compute the RMSE between these two array  but I don't want a scalar I would like to compute the RMSE for each point latitude, longitude so as output I would have a map where the colors would represent the variation of the RMSE.

Comment: Which sqrt and mean_squared_error are you using? Please show your imports